# Complex number lemma

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Suppose $p$ is a prime number, $ a_0, a_1, \cdots,a_{p-1} \in \mathbb{Q}$  and $\zeta$ is the primitive $p$-th root of unity. I need to show that
$$a_0 + a_1 \zeta + \cdots + a_{p-1} \zeta^{p-1} = 0 \iff a_0 = a_1 = \cdots = a_{p-1}$$

The inverse statement is obvious. What I did so far is take the polynomials $f(x)=a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_{p-1} x^{p-1}$ and $g(x)=1+  x + \cdots + x^{p-1}$. They have the common root $\zeta$ and $g$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$. I just need to prove that $g$ divides $f$.

I heve been searching for the proof of this lemma for like 2 hours and I still haven't found it. I think it's a really simple lemma but I'm missing something.

Comment: May be there is a typo, could you control that the right side of the $\iff$ is $a_0 = \dots = a_{p-1} = 0$ ?

Comment: But I think they don't have to be $0$ because $1+  \zeta + \cdots + \zeta^{p-1}=0$ and it would just be $a_0(1+  \zeta + \cdots + \zeta^{p-1})=0$.

Comment: If $\zeta$ is a root of both $f$ and $g$, then it is a root of the greatest common factor $d(x)$ of $g,f$. Since $g$ is irreducible, then either $d=1$ (which cannot be) or $d=g$ and $g|f$

Comment: Read about Cyclotomic polynomials. The cyclotomic polynomial of order $\;p\;$ is precisely $\;\Phi_p(x)=1+x+\ldots+x^{p-1}\;$ . It's not hard, though it is not trivial, to show that $\;\Phi_p\;$ is irreducible over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ and, in fact, it is the minimal polynomial of $\;\zeta\;$, so this polynomial must divide anyother rational polynomial vanishing at $\;\zeta\;$ (this is exactly what is written in the answer below). Observe that in fact $\;x^p-1=(x-1)\Phi(p(x)\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

In the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}$, $g(x) = 1 + x + \cdots + x^{p-1}$ is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$. Your $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ that has $\zeta$ as a root, so it is divisible by the minimal polynomial.